# How to change rel to nofollow with Regex - c#

Tags: c#, regex, nofollow

i want to change some urls to nofollow and i also want, some urls dofollow

i try to do it with this Regex :

```
(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)((?!blogs.cc)[^"]+)"([^>]*)>
```

i can support one url to dofollow (in this ex:"blogs.cc")

if i want to dofollow more of one, what do i do?
i try with :

```
(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)(((?!blogs.cc)[^"]+)||((?!wikipedia.org)[^"]+))"([^>]*)>
```

but i didn't get a correct answer

what's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved it and put my solution here for everybody who has same question.

just do it

```
(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)((?!(?:blogs.cc|wikipedia.org|moreUrls.com))[^"]+))"([^>]*)>
```

C# Sample Code:

```
Regex.Replace(str, "(<a\\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href=\"https?://)((?!(?:blogs.cc|wikipedia.org))[^\"]+)\"([^>]*)>", "<a $2$3\" $4 rel=\"nofollow\">")
```

i hope it would be useful

Comment: This pattern seems overly complicated...can you provide examples of what the processing will hit?